# I am trying to make a directory in the same one, where my file is but it makes it in "venv"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

[Here I try to create a directory in HelloWorld but it is making it in venv instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSqb2.png)

Basically, every time i want to make, find or interact with a directory in any way it is referring to `.\HelloWorld\venv` instead of `.\HelloWorld`

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need to use a lib to get a system path, the 'os' package can deal with that:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.mkdir(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "YOUR_FOLDER_NAME"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be specified in run configuration through `Working directory` setting, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html